# Check how much memory or CPU is being used per app, for all running apps

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to analyze how much memory, battery and cpu usage is taken by each app that is currently running on my iOS device. I don't mind if this can be done programmatically or otherwise. I have XCode up and running and I realize it can be used to check the CPU/memory of apps I install and run on my device.

Just to be clear, I do not want the total CPU/memory usage, but rather per app for all apps that are currently running.

Is this possible in iOS 8.1, *in any way*, without jailbreaking my device?

**Edit:** I just tried out Instruments in XCode and I realize to use it, you need to be testing an app. Is it possible to use Instruments to get this system info, without testing a new app? Can I get this info from the terminal for example? Thanks.